# DocuSign: Error calling CreateEnvelope

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have the following code for adding a new Envelope with a local file:

```
EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    Status = "sent"
};

// Get the contract file
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("[Local Filename]");

// Add a document to the envelope
DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document doc = new DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document();
doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
doc.Name = contract.FileName;
doc.DocumentId = "1";

envelope.Documents = new List<DocuSign.eSign.Model.Document>();
envelope.Documents.Add(doc);

// Add a recipient to sign the documeent
Signer signer = new Signer();
signer.Email = recipientEmail;
signer.Name = recipientName;
signer.RecipientId = "1";

// Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
signHere.DocumentId = "1";
signHere.PageNumber = "1";
signHere.RecipientId = "1";
signHere.XPosition = "100";
signHere.YPosition = "150";
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);

envelope.Recipients = new Recipients();
envelope.Recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
envelope.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);

DocuSignAuthentication Creds = new DocuSignAuthentication
{
    Username = "[My Username]",
    Password = "[My Password]",
    IntegratorKey = "[My Integration Key]"
};

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXXXX");

string authHeader = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Creds);
DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration cfg = new DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration(apiClient);
cfg.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(cfg);

EnvelopeSummary response = envelopeApi.CreateEnvelope("XXXXXXX", envelope);
```

The server returns a very little information in the error:

```
[ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: ]

DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition, CreateEnvelopeOptions options) in
Y:\dev\SDKs\csharp\sdk\src\main\csharp\DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi.cs:2606

DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition, CreateEnvelopeOptions options) in Y:\dev\SDKs\csharp\sdk\src\main\csharp\DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi.cs:2532
[Rest of the stack trace relates to our code]
```

If we try to use fiddler to capture any error messages from the server, the error becomes:

Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Is there anyway to get a more information about what's wrong with our request?  Or is there an un-encrypted developer endpoint available to work through these kinds of issues?  Any help you can spare would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like an ssl error, but it can be something else...are you sure that you have the right hour-date in your system clock?

Comment: Please use the API log tool and post the log entry for your call. See [blog entry](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-signature-api-logging-made-easy/)  You can edit your question to post the additional information

Comment: As a test, have you tried sending the same request through the DocuSign API Explorer?  You can create the same payload through the visual tool, then match that to the request body your code creates:  https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/

Answer (score 0):

The error "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel" means that the HTTPRequest call from the client (which can be your server, but is a client in the sense that it made the HTTPRequest) to the server (DocuSign in this case) could not use TLS over SSL (https:// address) to ensure that there's a certificate that allows to encrypt the information in the HTTPRequest and HttpResponse. This can happen for a variety of reasons including not having the current version of TLS on the client as well as having the wrong certificate or other issues with the network. I would recommend trying to make this call from a different server, potentially outside your corporate network to isolate the problem. Also, check the version of TLS to ensure it's at least 1.1